# How to get the Push Notifications displayed in the Notification center

Tags: swift, notifications, system-tray

All of these came from just one app I'm currently developing, let's call this app **SampleApp**

How do I get a list of these notifications from my Phone's Tray

[image]

Yes I do know that I may be able to get the notifications via this code

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {           
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (requests) in
        print("here are the iOS 10 notifs \(requests)")
    }         
} else {
    let requests = (UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications ?? [])
    print("here are the NON iOS 10 notifs \(requests)")
}
```

But the problem with this code is that I can only get notifications which *I created offline*, and not those coming from the **Apple Push Notification Server (APNS)**

By created offline I mean, scheduled `UILocalNotification`s, and since **Push Notifications** aren't `UILocalNotification`s I have no idea what to do

**Some Questions You May ask**

1. Are these notifications from my app?

   - Yes
2. Am I using the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` on the `AppDelegate`?

   - Yes, but that's different.
3. Does my remote notifications work/come from APNS

   - Yes.
4. What does my code for registering remote notifications look like?

   ```
   if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
       let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
       let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       center.delegate = self
       center.requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (_, _) in })
   } else {
       let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
       application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
   }

   application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
   ```

Comment: Why don't you use `UNUserNotificationCenter.current.getDeliveredNotifications()`? Also, there is no such thing as a "tray" in iOS, what you are referring to is called the Notification centre.

Comment: Update answer and accept yourself.

Comment: @user3589771 I can't yet because I still have no way of fetching these notifications for devices below `iOS 10`

Comment: Lesser than iOS 10 use `NSUserDefault` if no other way to get your notifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dávid Pásztor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667835/d%C3%A1vid-p%C3%A1sztor)'s comment partially solved the issue because now I can retrieve the **all** (push and non push) Notifications displayed in the **Notification Center**, but only for `iOS 10` because the code below is only for `iOS 10` devices and above, what about other versions?

```swift
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { (notifications) in
    print(notifications)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Zonily, are you able to read another apps push notifications, for example Instagram and iMessage, or only notifications from your app?

Comment: @stackich it's not possible to read other app notifications.