# IOS/Objective-C: Get list of pending notifications from notification center

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to get list of local notifications for my app that are in the notification center so I can display these in the app.

I found this code in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45732146/how-to-get-the-push-notifications-displayed-in-the-notification-center) but it is in Swift.  Can anyone translate to Objective-C or suggest how to get the notifications that have fired but are pending in Objective-C?

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {           
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests { (requests) in
        print("here are the iOS 10 notifs \(requests)")
    }         
} else {
    let requests = (UIApplication.shared.scheduledLocalNotifications ?? [])
    print("here are the NON iOS 10 notifs \(requests)")
}
```

Comment: `[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] getPendingNotificationRequestsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<UNNotificationRequest *> *requests){NSLog("requests: %@", requests);}];`? You need to copy/paste the method and check the doc, then find the definition in Objective-C. it's quite easy since they are SDK native methods.

Comment: That's a good tip!